# How to Ignore some query and execute the rest of query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I Have 5 databases with some structures are the same and some are not, like the `tbl_employee_debitcredit` this table is not in the other database i'd like to ignore the query that is not in the database table and let the other query execute. is that possible? if yes how? reference is enough. thanks

EDITED : this is the for loop and query im using if 1 table is missing it will stop the whole query and proceed to another database

```
Dim y As Integer = 0
For x = 0 To Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items.Count + 1
    Dim a As Integer = 0

    Dim constr As String = "Server=" & Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 3).Text & "Database=" & Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 4).Text & ";User id=" & Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 5).Text & ";password=" & Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 6).Text & ";Convert Zero Datetime=True;"
    'MessageBox.Show(constr)

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(constr)

    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim sqlcmd1 As New MySqlCommand("Select * from " &
            "(SELECT count(id) as Dept from departments where is_deleted = 0) as Dept, " &
            "(SELECT count(payroll_group_id) as pg from payroll_groups where is_deleted = 0) as pg , " &
            "(SELECT count(payroll_group_rate_id) as pgr from payroll_group_rates) as pgr, " &
            "(SELECT count(id) as leaves from leaves where is_deleted = 0) as leaves, " &
            "(SELECT count(id) as deminimis from de_minimis_benefits where is_deleted = 0 )as deminimis, " &
            "(SELECT employee_id from tbl_employee_debitcredit where is_deleted = 0 like '%1') and is_deleted = 0) as noODC ", conn)

        Dim dr1 As MySqlDataReader

        dr1 = sqlcmd1.ExecuteReader

        If dr1.HasRows Then
            While dr1.Read
                Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()

                newitem.Text = Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 1).Text.ToString
                newitem.SubItems.Add(Form1.UcAddClient1.lv_acc.Items(x).SubItems(y + 2).Text.ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("Dept").ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("pg").ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("pgr").ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("leaves").ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("deminimis").ToString)
                newitem.SubItems.Add(dr1.Item("noODC").ToString)
                lv_client_tracker.Items.Add(newitem)

            End While

            dr1.Close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

    End If

Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point here. Are you trying to create _one_ `MySqlCommand` to use with _two different_ `MySqlConnection` objects? Why not create two `MySqlCommand`s as well?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i have for loop to open each connection in my database and i have this query command to execute for each database, and some of those database i don't have the structure like table tbl_employee_debitcredit  and i'd like to ignore that specific SELECT  and execute the rest of query . is that possible?

Comment: Make a new query just with what you want. It is easear to select wich query to execute than selecting which part of the query to execute

Comment: @nacho The connection and query is inside of the for loop i can't  make a new query for that.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, if you code it correctly.  If it's not working the way you're trying, you're not doing it right.  We'd need to see what you're doing to tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out if the table exists in the according environment. I don't know the exact syntax in mysql but it should not be hard to find out, I just created an empty function to simulate it. Then you append the according query, either the real one or a dummy one returning 0 (or -1 or whatever you like) instead.

```
Private Sub Foo()
    Dim myExistsDepartments As Boolean = TableExists("departments", conn)
    Dim myExistsPayrollGroups As Boolean = TableExists("payroll_groups", conn)
    Dim myExistsPayrollGroupRates As Boolean = TableExists("payroll_group_rates", conn)
    Dim myExistsLeaves As Boolean = TableExists("leaves", conn)
    Dim myExistsDeMinimisBenefits As Boolean = TableExists("de_minimis_benefits", conn)
    Dim myExistsTblEmployeeDebitCredit As Boolean = TableExists("tbl_employee_debitcredit", conn)

    Dim myCommand As New StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ")
    If (myExistsDepartments) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM departments WHERE is_deleted = 0) AS Dept, ")
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS Dept, ")
    End If
    If (myExistsPayrollGroups) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT COUNT(payroll_group_id) FROM payroll_groups WHERE is_deleted = 0) AS pg, ")
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS pg, ")
    End If
    If (myExistsPayrollGroupRates) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT COUNT(payroll_group_rate_id) FROM payroll_group_rates) AS pgr, ")
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS pgr, ")
    End If
    If (myExistsLeaves) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT count(id) FROM leaves WHERE is_deleted = 0) AS leaves, ")
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS leaves, ")
    End If
    If (myExistsDeMinimisBenefits) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT count(id) FROM de_minimis_benefits WHERE is_deleted = 0) AS deminimis, ")
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS deminimis, ")
    End If
    If (myExistsTblEmployeeDebitCredit) Then
        myCommand.Append("(SELECT employee_id FROM tbl_employee_debitcredit where is_deleted = 0) AS noODC ")
        'Or however this query should read correctly...
    Else
        myCommand.Append("0 AS noODC ")
    End If
    Dim sqlcmd1 As New MySqlCommand(myCommand.ToString(), conn)


End Sub

Private Function TableExists(tableName As String, conn As MySqlConnection) As Boolean
    'Put code here...
    Return True
End Function
```